# How do I export regex to CSV and ensure that each grouping goes into the correct column?

Tags: php, regex, csv

I've created the regular expression to group the data I need to collect. However, I'm really lost as to how I go about exporting this.

Here's what I've done https://regex101.com/r/C7KvkH/5

What I need to do next is to have 4 columns in a spreadsheet, such as LibreOffice Spreadsheet or Google Sheets. So I need the data to correspond to the following columns:

'frequency' group 1 -first column, 'word' group 2  -second column, 'gender' group 3 -third column, 'sentence' group 4 -fourth column

Do I save this data to a text file and then change it to a CSV file?

Do I need to create tabs?

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I think you want this https://regex101.com/r/C7KvkH/6. But, this works as well https://regex101.com/r/PJfxQf/1

Comment: Links to live regex testers are welcome here, but please also show the expression in the question as well. Without that, if the link dies, the question dies too, and will have to be deleted.

Comment: Thank halfer. I've made some progress and scaled it up to see if it's working correctly https://regex101.com/r/C7KvkH/12. However, I'm having a small niggle with the 1st group. 'el, la' should both be in group 2 and 'art' should be group 3. Seems a comma and a space are causing the problem. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks. ([0-9]+)\s+(\w+,?)\s+(\w+).*?\r?\n•\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+[0-9]+\s\|.*\s*

Answer (score 0):

I have expanded on the pattern that I provided for your second question / sample of text (French).

This pattern works with both of your sample texts (French and Spanish). It provides five capture groups as per your second question.

```
/^(\d+) +(\w+(?:, ?\w+)*) +([acdefijlmnoprtuv()]+(?:, ?[acdefijlmnoprtuv()]+)*) +([\S\s]+?)\n\x{2022} +([\S\s]+?)\n\d+ \| [-+\dno ]+\s*/um
```

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/C7KvkH/15)

See my remarks at [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45400275/2943403).

Adjustments to my other pattern:

- Expanded the second capture group to allow comma separated values.  e.g. `el, la`
- Added `u` to the character classes of capture group 3. (for #56 & #72)
- Expanded last character class to `[-+\dno ]` for occurrences like text block #8.

After using this pattern with `preg_replace()` to perform the desired tabbing, you can use php's menu of csv functions to produce the file that you need.

Comment: Just noticed your answer for this question as well. Thanks a lot for all your help, really appreciate it.