# How to optionally add a comma and whitespace to a capture group?

Tags: php, regex, option-type, substring, capture-group

I am trying to match five substrings in each block of text (there are 100 blocks total).

I am matching 99% of the blocks of text, but with a few errors regarding groups 3 and 4.

Here is a demo link: https://regex101.com/r/cW2Is3/4

Group 3 is "parts of speech", and group 4 is an English translation.

In the first block of text, `det, pro` should all be in group 3, and then `the; him, her, it, them` should be in group 4.

The same issue occurs again in the third block of text.
Group 3 should be `adj, det, nm, pro` and Group 4 should be `a, an, one`.

This is my pattern:

```
([0-9]+)\s+(\w+(?:, \w+)?)\s+(\N+?)\s+(\H.+).*?\r?\n•\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+[0-9]+\s\|.*\s*
```

Answer (score 1):

Voici...

```
/^(\d+) +(\w+) +([acdefijlmnoprtv()]+(?:, ?[acdefijlmnoprtv()]+)*) +([\S\s]+?)\n\x{2022} +([\S\s]+?)\n\d+ \| [-\dn]+\s*/gum
```

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/cW2Is3/6)

I have done my best to optimize the pattern. I shaved nearly 10,000 steps off of your pattern and reached 100 matches as desired.

- Starting anchor `^` is used to identify start of each block (Efficiency / Accuracy)
- `\d` is used instead of `[0-9]` (Brevity)
- `\s` is replaced with a literal space where applicable (Brevity)
- A character class of specific letters and parentheses was used in place of `\w` for capture group 3. (Efficiency) *could be replaced with `[\w()]` for brevity with a loss of efficiency
- The bullet was specified using the literal `\x{2022}` (Personal preference)
- Character class used on trailing characters of each block `[-\dn]`. (Efficiency / Accuracy)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you know your stuff on this. Can you recommend a good book to help me out? I'm just not an expert on this. Been trying to break the  French to English sentence into 2 groups with no luck.

Comment: @user8383901 You want Casimir's awesome answer. His splits the English and French sentences (without you asking for it).  Just add another capture group in the replacement box.  Where did I learn to regex?  Right here on SO.  I watch the best posters and learn from their expertise.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to describe a long string with many parts, the first reflex is to use the free-space mode (x modifier) and named groups (even if named groups aren't very useful in a replacement context, they help to make the pattern readable and more easy to debug):

```
~^
(?<No> [0-9]+ )  \h+
(?<word> \pL+ )  \h+
(?<type> [\pL()]+ (?: , \h* [\pL()]+ )* )  \h+
(?<wd_tr> [^•]* [^•\s] )  \h* \R

• \h*
(?<sent_fr> [^–]* [^\s–] )   \s* – \s*
(?<sent_eng> .* (?:\R .*)*? )  \h* \R

(?<num1> [0-9]+ )  \h* \| \h*
(?<num2> .*\S )
~xum
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/6RQ8D6/3)

There are no magic recipe to build a pattern for a string with a blurred format. All you can do is to be the most constrictive at the beginning and to add flexibility when you encounter cases that don't match.

Comment: Awesome pattern.  (I didn't use enough negated character classes) Please post an answer to this user's other question.  Why all of the `\h`'s? I am still digesting why your pattern is ~3x faster than mine.

Comment: Thanks, there are different reasons for the `\h`s: it's useful to return trimmed groups, it's more restrictive than `\s` since it isn't allowed to jump to the next line, I prefer to write `\h*\R` in place of `\s` to be sure there's a newline... One of the keys to reduce the step numbers is to avoid the most possible non-greedy quantifiers or to reduce the impact of a non-greedy quantifier using a group: for example `(?:\R.*)*?` takes a whole line (1 test per line) and is better than `(?s).*?` (1 test per character).

Comment: 3x less steps doesn't always mean 3x faster.

Comment: Thanks Casimir. Naming the groups is a handy tip. You're one step ahead in realising I wanted to divide the French–English sentence. I was using the substitutions to extract it into a database. With the addition to an extra tab (6) for the English sentence, it seems to overlap with the the first group (No) when placed in a database. Any ideas?

Comment: @user8383901: sorry but I don't see what you mean.

Comment: Hi Casimir. Currently the substitution is \1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\n, so that each grouping is divided by a tab. This allows me to simply highlight the text below 'Substitution' and export to LibreOffice, with each grouping going into 5 different columns. When I add an additional tab for group 6, like this \1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\6\t\n, it causes the 6th group to divide between the 6th and 1st column, when it should all be in the 6th column. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user8383901: ok, this is probably because several english sentences contains a newline. You can try to protect these sentences putting them between double quotes.